# Using Residue Theorem to calculate the integral

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

for $$I=\int_{|z|=1}{z^m \cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}\,dz$$
where $m=0,1,2...$

Is the singularity $z=0$ or there are some other singularities?

if it is $z=0$, what's order of pole?

Comment: Point $z=0$ is an essential singularity of $\cos\dfrac{1}{z}$. This implies from the Laurent expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
I=\int_{|z|=1}{z^m \cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}\,dz
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1}z^{m-2n}\,dz,
$$
and that
$$
\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1}z^{m-2n}\,dz=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc} 2\pi i & \text{if} & m-2n=-1,\\
0 & \text{if} & m-2n\ne-1. \end{array}\right.
$$
So, if $m$ is even, then $I=0$, while if $m=2k-1$, then
$$
I=\frac{2\pi i(-1)^k}{(2k)!}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$z=0$ is the only singularity, and it is not a pole.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=1/\zeta$; then the integral is equal to

$$-\int_{|\zeta|=1} d\zeta \frac{\cos{\zeta}}{\zeta^{m+2}} $$

which, by Cauchy's theorem, is

$$\frac{i 2 \pi}{(m+1)!} \left [\frac{d^{m+1}}{d\zeta^{m+1}} \cos{\zeta}\right ]_{\zeta=0} = \begin{cases} 0 & m \; \text{even} \\  \displaystyle \frac{i 2 \pi (-1)^{\frac{m+1}{2}}}{(m+1)!} & m \; \text{odd}\end{cases}$$

Note that, in substituting, we traverse the circle in the opposite direction; thus we multiply by $-i 2 \pi$.